# How to set variable boolean value in next powershell task in azure devops yml task to find it's true or false and then set value accordingly?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have below task in my yml but when I try to store the value of $(setOutput.myOutputJobVar) in some variable in powershell azure devops yml it is not working and saying the term "true" is not recognized as a cmdlet, function etc.

Any idea?

```
jobs:
- job: A
  steps:
  - powershell: |
     Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputJobVar;isoutput=true]this is the same job too"
    name: setOutput

  - powershell: |
     Write-Host $(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)
```

I want something

```
$a = $(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)
if ($a -eq 'true') { $var = "Hello" } else { "" }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the value '**`true`**' as **String** type to the PowerShell variable '**`$a`**' by using the quotes to surround the expression '**`$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)`**'.

```
$a = '$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)'
```

So, on the second and subsequent PowerShell tasks within the same job, you can do like as below:

```yaml
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Use output variable'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          Write-Host "setOutput.myOutputJobVar = $(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)"
          $a = '$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)'
          if ( $a -eq 'true' )
          {
            Write-Host "The value of output variable is true."
          }
          else
          {
            Write-Host "The value of output variable is not true."
          }
```

[image]

---

Another way is as **`@Scott Richards`** mentioned, you can add an extra '**`$`**' before the expression '**`$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)`**' to pass the value '**`true`**' as **Boolean** type to the PowerShell variable '**`$a`**'.

```
$a = $$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)
```

So, on the second and subsequent PowerShell tasks within the same job, you can do like as below:

```yaml
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'Use output variable'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: |
          Write-Host "setOutput.myOutputJobVar = $(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)"
          $a = $$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)
          if ( $a -eq $true )
          {
            Write-Host "The value of output variable is true."
          }
          else
          {
            Write-Host "The value of output variable is not true."
          }
```

[image]

---

Comment: @unknown, Is there any update from you? Have you tried the methods shared in my above answer to pass a Boolean value to a PowerShell variable? Do the methods work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Azure DevOps pipelines are always stored as strings.

You can prepend another `$` before the variable reference to turn it into a boolean as far as powershell is concerned like so:

```
$a = $$(setOutput.myOutputJobVar)
```